Confidence intervals around Q-matrix values from multiple STRUCTURE runs
Context: I've run STRUCTURE on a set of 84 individuals (RADseq data) for a range of K values (2--7). I've specified 20 replicate STRUCTURE runs per K value, and these were passed to CLUMPAK to summarize results within and across K values, generating a summary Q-matrix for each K value.
Question: is there a way to calculate confidence intervals surrounding these summary Q-matrices? My preference is to do so using CLUMPAK, but I am open to other options if they're available. The output of each STRUCTURE run generates a text file containing a Q-matrix, but it isn't clear to me how to combine these for multiple runs to generate confidence intervals.
Thanks for any suggestions!

If we consult the structure docs, we observe that they directly address the idea of a $Q$ distribution for each individual (p. 24), in the form of a Bayesian credible interval, which can be obtained by using the ANCESTDIST flag. Example output is shown on p.34.
It is not clear to me how to summarize across runs given the different initializations, but I'd trust the internal methods more.
I am unsure how to integrate this with CLUMPAK. I'd say that they are probably two different ways of getting at a conceptually similar interpretation.

Thanks--setting the ANCESTDIST flag to 1 did generate Bayesian Credible intervals surrounding each value in the Q matrix, for each STRUICTURE run.
I will look into how to combine these results across runs.
